# Global variable not recognized

Tags: google-apps-script, global-variables

I'm using a global variable (destination_id) but it's not recognized in the doPost function. I get the message: Exception: Argument non valide : id (line 136, file "Code")

```
var destination_id ="111111111111111";
function doPost(e) {
const destination = 
DriveApp.getFolderById(destination_id);
}
```

BUt when i use the variable inside the doPost function it works.

```
function doPost(e) {

var destination_id ="111111111111111";
const destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(destination_id);


}
```

Comment: About `Exception: Argument non valide : id`, in this case, how did you run the script?

Comment: In my Html page, i have a button named "Save". When i click on, the script is executed

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood that you had run your top script using HTML form from the outside of the Google Apps Script to the Web Apps. If my understanding is correct, when I tested it using the valid folder ID, no error occurred. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. For example, when you reflect your latest script to your Web Apps again and test it again, what result will you obtain?

Comment: Thanks. I was using a duplicate variable names. Now, it's solved.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question for others who have the same issue. I was using a duplicate variable names. Be sure to use a unique variable name.

Comment: In particular you were declaring your local variable the same name as your global one.